# Can I perform concurrent request and modificatio using PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I have a mysql table with a lot of data in it. All of the rows in this table need to have one field modified in a way that is not easily expressed in pure SQL.

I'd like to be able to loop over the table row by row, and update all the entries one by one.
However to do this I would do something like:

```
$sql = "SELECT id,value FROM objects";
foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row)
{
    $value = update_value( $row['value'] );
    $id = $row['id'];
    $update_sql = "UPDATE objects SET value='$value' WHERE id=$d";
    $dbh->query( $update_sql );
}
```

Will this do something bad? (Other than potentially being slow?)

Clarification: In particular I'm worried about the first select using a cursor, rather than retrieving all the data in one hit within the foreach, and then
there being something I don't know about cursor invalidation caused by the update inside the loop. If there is some rule like "don't update the same table while scanning it with another cursor" it's likely that it will only show up on huge tables, and so me performing a small test case is pretty much useless.

If someone can point me to docs that say doing this is OK, rather than a particular problem with working this way, that'd also be great.

Comment: is it one-shot action run in the background or a live action performed per user request?

Comment: Its a one shot function related to an application schema change. The rest of the application will be brought down while it runs. Speed is not really a major concern here.

Comment: So, what is your problem when? I suppose you'd have your action done already if just run this code instead of posting it here:)

Comment: It may be one shot per database, but it does need to be run on hundreds of database, some small, some large, some here, some there ... I'd rather not subtly break any of them, or miss migrating some entries.

Comment: 2 potential problems I can think of is that something else is updating your same table while this process runs. If this is a possibility then you should probably lock table, then run process then unlock table.
Another problem is if something fails in the middle of this process you will end up with some rows updated and some not updated. To deal with this situation you need to use transactions beginTransaction(),  update all rows, endTransaction()

Comment: voting to close as not a real question. "I have a table" in the question body slightly contradicts with "I have hundreds of databases" in the comments.

Comment: Hundreds of databases, each with one copy of this big fat table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results of a single query are consistent, so updates won't affect it. To keep in mind:

1. Use prepared statements; it will reduce the traffic between your process and the database, because only the values are transferred instead of a whole query every time.
2. If you're worried about other processes running at the same time, you should use transactions and proper locking, e.g.

   ```
   // transaction started
   SELECT id,value 
   FROM objects 
   LOCK IN SHARE MODE

   // your other code

   // commit transaction
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have two options right out of the gate:

1. (straight-forward): use something like 'fetchAll' to get all the results of the first query before you start looping through it. this will help keep you from overlapping cursors.
2. (more obscure): change this to use a stored function (in place of 'update_value') so you can turn the two queries into a single 'update objects set value=some_function( id )'

Depending on the size and duration of this you may need to lock everything beforehand.